Prevent connection of ends of a partial circle in a 3D tikz picture
I want to draw a 3-dimensional parabola (i.e. plot $z=x^2 + y^2$) with maximal value of z=1 and then mark the part of the parabola where $x^2 + y^2 =1$, $x\leq 0$ and $y \leq 0$, which is part of a circle.
I have the following code
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[radius=1]
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$l_1$, ylabel=$l_2$, zlabel=$u$, 
            xmin=-1, xmax=1,
            ymin=-1, ymax=1,
            zmin=-0.1, zmax=1.05,
            %x={(-0.125cm,-0.05cm)}, y={(0.125cm,-0.05cm)}, z={(0cm,0.05cm)},
            axis lines=middle,
            every axis x label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
            every axis y label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
            every axis z label/.style={  at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},  },
            colormap/blackwhite,]
            % Paraboloid
            \addplot3[surf,
            samples=50,
            shader=interp, draw=lightgray, ultra thin, 
            opacity=0.5, fill opacity=0.5,
            data cs=polar, domain=0:360, 
            y domain=0:1,
            restrict z to domain=0:1, 
            ](x, y, y^2);
            % Part of parabola
            \addplot3[surf,
            samples=50,
            shader=interp, draw=lightgray, fill=green, ultra thin,
            left color=green, right color=green, middle color=green!25,  
            data cs=polar, domain=180:270, 
            y domain=0:1,
            restrict z to domain=0:1, 
            ](x, y, y^2);
            %partial circle
            \addplot3[
            domain=180:270,
            samples=20,
            variable=\t,
            color=red,
            ultra thin,
            ] ({cos(\t)}, {sin(\t)}, {1});
        \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}


I do not want to connect the end points of the partial circle. How do I prevent this from happening?

Add sample y=0 for the partial circle.  By the way, I don't get your drawing if I use your code.

Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!
I think you have a little type, so if anybody else has the same problem, what worked for me is adding samples y=0.
